# What is the right association between these two models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, associations

I am building a blog and I am a Rails newbie. The doubt is about how to stablish the association between these too models: Posts and Languages.

There will be just two languages, and each post will only (belong_to/has) one language. I was thinking that the right thing would be:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :language
end

class Language < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end
```

Is it the right approach? Cause sounds more natural to think that a post has_one language and a language belongs_to_many posts but this kind of association isn't possible in rails, am i wrong?.

Sorry for such an newbie question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct. If you have two models in a many-to-one relationship, your only option is to put `has_many` on the "one" model and `belongs_to` on the "many" model. So, in your case, you do indeed want the snippet you provided.

Remember that this means your `posts` table will carry a `language_id` column (which feels right), and that your code will refer to `post.language` and `language.posts`.